# Updating Custom Columns in 2013 Task in SPD

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a field that is input by the user in task 1, when that task is complete a second task is created and I would like the input in task 1 to be displayed in a site column in task 2 as is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to do this in SharePoint 2013 workflow or SharePoint 2010 type workflow?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 workflow